# How to insert values using PHP MySQl UPDATE clause?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Below is the HTML form which takes input subject & beginner(yes,no) from user and inserts it into database

```
<form action="coursesignup.php" method="post">
    Select Subject:<br>
     <select name="subject">
        <option value="select" selected>select</option>
        <option value="Database Management Systems">Database Management Systems</option>
        <option value="Advanced Microprocessors">Advanced Microprocessors</option>    </select><br><br>
        Are you a Beginner:<br>
        <select name="beginner">
        <option value="select" selected>select</option>
        <option value="yes">yes</option>
        <option value="no">No</option></select><br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>
```

Form submits the data into following php file.
However, it is not inserting the values at the respective userid but putting them at the end of the table

```
<?php

session_start();

if($_SESSION["username"])
$_POST["username"]=$_SESSION["username"];
$user=$_POST["username"];

// Check connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","elearning");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security

$subject = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['subject']);
$beginner= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['beginner']);

$sql=" UPDATE student_info SET subject=$subject AND beginner=$beginner 
       WHERE username=$user " ;



if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "Successfuly entered";


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

It gives following error:

> Error: Erreur de syntaxe près de 'Management Systems AND ;beginner=yes WHERE username=gk4316' à la ligne 1

Comment: As the error message says, it seems that you have an extra (unnecessary) Semicolon in the query after the AND in : Management Systems AND **;** beginner=yes WHERE username=gk4316 , you also need to wrap the username value in quotes

Comment: @Ormoz That is what SQL produced as the error, it's not the query itself. The OP's SQL is in French and I can understand that language.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your query.

You need to use quotes around your variables, since you are passing those as strings.

Another problem is, you need to remove the `AND` and use a comma instead.

```
$sql=" UPDATE student_info SET subject='$subject', beginner='$beginner' 
       WHERE username='$user' " ;
```

That is why you're getting the error message.

- For more information on `SET` visit: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-update-query.htm
  and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-statement.html

---

`AND` is where you wish to use multiple checks in a `WHERE` clause.

For example:

```
`WHERE column_1 = 'something' AND column_2 = 'something else'
```

---

Sidenote:

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

Footnotes:

Something else I spotted is `if($_SESSION["username"])`. You're better off using [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) `if(isset($_SESSION["username"]))` and using proper bracing:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){
  $_POST["username"]=$_SESSION["username"];
  $user=$_POST["username"];
}
```

It's just good coding practice.

---

***A quick tutorial:***

Here is an example of an UPDATE using `mysqli` with prepared statements:

Sidenote: `i` stands for `integer` and `s` stands for `string`.

```
$con = new mysqli('host','user','password','database');
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE `table` SET `title`=?, `description`=?, `price`=?, `location`=?, `email`=?, `date`=? WHERE `id`=?");
$stmt->bind_param("ssisssi", $title_string, $description_string, $price_int, $location_string, $email_string, $date_string, $id_int);
stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the AND and replace it with a comma in your sql update statement.

$sql=" UPDATE student_info SET subject='$subject', beginner='$beginner' 
       WHERE username='$user' " ;